# Drawing Images in JavaScript (Pro HTML Games)

Tags: javascript, html

Given the following code to draw a spaceship image:

```
        // Get a handle to the image object
        var image = document.getElementById('spaceship');

        // Draw the image at (0,350)
        context.drawImage(image,0,350); - error on this line

        // Scaling the image to half the original size
        context.drawImage(image,0,400,100,25);

        // Drawing part of the image
        context.drawImage(image,0,0,60,50,0,420,60,50);
```

In the HTML after this script there is this code:

```
        <img src = "spaceship.png" id = "spaceship">
```

I am using a different image to the image in the book but presumably the actual image doesn't matter (have tested the image by itself). I have an error on the second line: context.drawImage(image,0,350); - uncaught reference error context is not defined.

Context has previously been defined in:

```
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Also it has worked for many other shapes but errors on that line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a `canvas` element on the page, get it with javascript, then get context from it and then use. Like this:

HTML:

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code in full:

```
    <body onload = "pageLoaded();">
    <canvas width = "640" height = "480" id = "testcanvas" style = "border:black 1px solid;">
    <script type = "text/javascript" charset = "utf-8">
        function pageLoaded() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('testcanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');




        // Get a handle to the image object
        var image = document.getElementById('spaceship');

        // Draw the image at (0,350)
        context.drawImage(image,0,350);

        // Scaling the image to half the original size
        context.drawImage(image,0,400,100,25);

        // Drawing part of the image
        context.drawImage(image,0,0,60,50,0,420,60,50);










    </script>

    </canvas>
    <img src="spaceship.png" id="spaceship">

</body>
```